# How to update Textures in ThreeJs?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to update my skybox textures by clicking on thumbnails.

It's based on this example : [canvas_geometry_panorama.html](http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_panorama.html)

The title of the thumbnail is matching with the folder that contains the skybox images.
So with a simple jQuery script it will generate a link to the folder:

```
$('.thumbs img').click(function() {
var myPath = 'img/' + $(this).attr("title") + '/';
});
```

next I fill in the var in the loadTexture:

```
var materials = [

                loadTexture(myPath+'lx.jpg'), // right
                loadTexture(myPath+'rx.jpg' ), // left
                loadTexture(myPath+'ly.jpg' ), // top
                loadTexture(myPath+'ry.jpg' ), // bottom
                loadTexture(myPath+'lz.jpg' ), // back
                loadTexture(myPath+'rz.jpg' )  // front

            ];
```

But it is not updating.. Why?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates
Does this help? :) Use material.needsUpdate = true;

Comment: I have seen that page but I don't know how to use it in the script. Any suggestions?